# Kentico update order item alternative form

Tags: forms, customization, kentico

I have to develop a custom module for Kentico e-commerce in which I want to display a form (in items tab of order) which lets me update the order item fields added by me in OrderItem modules such as ItemStatus and some more.

I want those fields to appear in "Order Item Properties" form (which appears in the items tab of order) along with the existing fields.

How can I do so using a custom module such that it overrides?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a custom module, you'd simply create that alternative form based on that class you create.  If you're not creating a class, then you can create an alternative form in another module class like Order or OrderItem.

For your particular example, I might simply create a new tab on the Order detail screen which allows you to edit those specific properties.  You'd create a custom aspx page which that UI element points to.  Then you can have your custom code in there as you wish, doing exactly what you want as I'm not 100% sure the OOTB functionality will do what you want.